# FacesContext not injectable in Wildfly 14 with JSF 2.3 (Mojarra, main module)

Tags: wildfly, cdi, faces-config, facescontext, jsf-2.3

I have a bean:

```
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

...

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SimpleBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    protected FacesContext facesContext;

    ...
}
```

According to

https://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/jsf-23.html#1316

this should work with 2.3 ...

When deploying to Wildfly 14, this results in:

```
13:02:33,516 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
13:02:33,563 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) Envers integration enabled? : true
13:02:34,344 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
13:02:34,531 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-1) WELD-000146: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType<?>) used for class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper is deprecated from CDI 1.1!
13:02:34,918 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."auth-portal.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."auth-portal.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1728)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type FacesContext with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject protected com.company.project.view.SimpleBean.facesContext
  at com.company.project.view.SimpleBean.facesContext(SimpleBean.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:378)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:526)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

13:02:34,918 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "auth-portal.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"auth-portal.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type FacesContext with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject protected com.company.project.view.SimpleBean.facesContext
  at com.company.project.view.SimpleBean.facesContext(SimpleBean.java:0)
"}}
```

My faces-config.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
              version="2.3">
    ...
```

**QUESTION**:

What's wrong here and how do you solve this?

BTW the answer here didn't solve it: [How to inject FacesContext with JSF 2.3 and TomEE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846590/how-to-inject-facescontext-with-jsf-2-3-and-tomee)

Comment: There's none being displayed out of the box, only `13:49:20,809 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]`. When using the expressions `JSF Version = #{facesContext.class.package.implementationTitle} #{facesContext.class.package.implementationVersion}` on one of the XHTMLs however, the string `JSF Version = Mojarra 2.3.5.SP2` is being displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to

https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra#activating-cdi-in-jsf-23

this is the answer:

> By default, JSF 2.3 will run in JSF 2.2 modus as to CDI support. Even
>   when you use a JSF 2.3 compatible `faces-config.xml`. In other words,
>   the new JSF 2.3 feature of injection and EL resolving of JSF artifacts
>   ([spec issue 1316](https://github.com/javaee/javaserverfaces-spec/issues/1316)) won't work until you explicitly activate this.
>   In other words, `@Inject FacesContext` doesn't work by default. This
>   is necessary in order for JSF 2.3 to be fully backwards compatible.
>
> There is currently only one way to activate CDI in JSF 2.3 and
>   herewith make JSF 2.3 to run in full JSF 2.3 modus. Put the
>   `@FacesConfig` annotation on an arbitrary CDI managed bean. For
>   example, a general startup/configuration bean.
>
> ```
> @FacesConfig
> @ApplicationScoped
> public class YourApplicationConfig {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Full example:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.annotation.FacesConfig;

@FacesConfig
@ApplicationScoped
public class Jsf23Activator {
    // ...
}
```

You need the `@ApplicationScoped` annotation or it will not work. After that in my startup the console finally displays:

```
14:23:28,805 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 82) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.5.SP2 for context '/blah'
14:23:30,415 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 82) Monitoring file:/C:/dev/servers/wildfly-14.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/blah.war/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
```

Comment: The trick here is the missing `@ApplicationScoped`... without it, nothing's happening.

Comment: As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682309/changing-faces-config-xml-from-2-2-to-2-3-causes-javax-el-propertynotfoundexcept

Comment: Yeah. And from what I tried, you don't need the extra `version = FacesConfig.Version.JSF_2_3`.